# How to find m in c = m^e (mod n) if c, e, n are known

Tags: language-agnostic, rsa, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose I have known java BigIntegers c, e, and n, is there a way to quickly calculate the BigInteger m, where:

```
c = m^e (mod n)
```

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: This problem really is not specific to Java... it's a number theory problem, no specific programming language will be able to decrypt RSA quickly without the secret key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sort of... Suppose that you have determined the number "d" such that

```
d*e=1  (mod phi(n))
```

Where phi(n) is the size of the set of relatively prime numbers relative to n. For example, if n=pq where p and q are prime, then phi(n)=(p-1)*(q-1).

Then

```
m=c^d (mod n)
```

In the case where you don't already know "d", then I think it is going to be pretty difficult for you to invert that function in general. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that I needed to solve this equation to solve the problem I am trying to crack, but it seems that there is another way to get the solution (as I don't know the value for "d", solving this would be very difficult).

Comment: You are being asked to break 2048 bit RSA encryption.

Comment: The "2048" in my comment is the the "n=2048" in your previous comment that appears to have been deleted... Anyways, generally it is hard to break this encryption.